# Rails can't generate migration for RailsGirlsBerlin App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

Edit: the problem was in the routing how I named it.

The problem routing code was

> get :to => redirect('attendees#index')

The fixing code was

> match "/attendees", to: 'attendee#index', via:'get'

I'm going through the RailsGirls app tutorial and I added and bundled the Geocoder and Gmaps4rails to `Gemfile` without any problem.  I run this and get the following error:

```
rails generate migration AddLatitudeAndLongitudeToAttendee latitude:float longitude:float
```

Here's the error:

```
/Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:229:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:116:in `normalize_options!'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:64:in `initialize'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in `new'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in `add_route'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1417:in `decomposed_match'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1398:in `block in match'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1389:in `each'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1389:in `match'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:596:in `map_method'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:557:in `get'
from /users/sungmoon/rails_project/railsgirls/config/routes.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `eval_block'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:294:in `draw'
from /users/sungmoon/rails_project/railsgirls/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /users/sungmoon/rails_project/railsgirls/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

First off, my I have an attendee controller and models. I saw a similar post but their problem was not having a controller. Can anybody tell me why I am getting this error message and what the problem is? I am new to  programming and not sure how to read it.

Comment: looks like you might have a similar problem to the other posts you saw - look at this line: `4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:229:in default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError) from /Users/sungmoon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-`

Comment: can you post your routes.rb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your routes.rb file and take a look at the controller file that the error references - check for spelling errors -- Here is a similar error message and the solution was just an error in the syntax - compare what you have to the tutorial and if you can't find the error - post the files here and get a second set of eyes on them!

[Why is my development server not loading? default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568301/why-is-my-development-server-not-loading-default-controller-and-action-missin)