# Rails 4 error when runnning the rails server command on console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been working on an application and just installed the twitter bootstrap gem and installed 'therubyracer' gem using the `https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows` tutorial, can anybody help with the following error I get when running 'rails server', any help here would be appreciated, I'm not sure whats gone wrong here?

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action
_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:229:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :con
troller (ArgumentError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:116:in `normalize_options!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:64:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in `add_route'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1417:in `decomposed_match'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1398:in `block in match'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1389:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1389:in `match'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:596:in `map_method'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:557:in `get'
        from C:/Sites/socialeyes/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)
>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `eval_block'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0
.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:294:in `draw'
        from C:/Sites/socialeyes/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from C:65535:in `execute_if_updated'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block i
n tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (
2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block i
n each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_e
ach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Sites/socialeyes/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/socialeyes/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/Sites/socialeyes/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Sites/socialeyes/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib
/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you try to use google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568301/why-is-my-development-server-not-loading-default-controller-and-action-missin

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a root route in your config/routes.rb file or at least one route.

Here is an exemple :

```
# At least a route (here for HelloController)
get '/hello' => 'hello#index'

# Or a root route
root 'hello#index'
```