# Rails server exits on startup. (Rails 4.0.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails server suddenly keeps exiting on startup. Though it worked perfectly a little while ago. I haven't tweaked anything since.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http: //0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

Exiting

/home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:229:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:116:in `normalize_options!'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:64:in `initialize'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1443:in `new'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1443:in `add_route'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1422:in `decomposed_match'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1403:in `block in match'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `each'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `match'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:601:in `map_method'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:570:in `post'
    from /home/kavya/lms/config/routes.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `eval_block'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:319:in `draw'
    from /home/kavya/lms/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/kavya/lms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/kavya/lms/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/kavya/lms/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/kavya/lms/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/kavya/lms/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in     `wrapped_app'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /home/kavya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This error is caused by setting the root path to a controller that doesn't exist.  For example, if you point the root to `foos#bar` and you don't have a foos controller defined, you get this error.

Comment: look up at your `routes.rb` file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my development server not loading? default\_controller\_and\_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568301/why-is-my-development-server-not-loading-default-controller-and-action-missin)

Comment: The controller exists.The config/routes.rb seemed fine. And it started working again without me having to tweak anything.

Answer (score 2):

As you can refer here..

[Why is my development server not loading? default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568301/why-is-my-development-server-not-loading-default-controller-and-action-missin)

It's because of syntax problem under `config/routes.rb` in your application:

Check your routes you may find like for example while defining `controller#action` in routes like below..

Syntax should not be like:

`root :to => 'home/index'`

Syntax should be like:

`root :to => 'home#index'`

Comment: The config/routes.rb seemed fine. And it started working again without me having to tweak anything.